# Howto create limited unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
  member_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  email text,
  archived boolean DEFAULT FALSE,
  CONSTRAINT members_email_key UNIQUE(email)
);
```

I need the unique-constraint to consider only the *active* members (that are note archived: `archived=False`). So the following would be valid:

```
insert into members(name, email) values('ulf','ulf@example.com');
insert into members(name, email) values('foo','foo@example.com');
insert into members(name, email) values('baz','baz@example.com');
update members set archived = True where name = 'ulf';
insert into members(name, email) values('Newulf','ulf@example.com');
```

But this should fail:

```
insert into members(name, email) values('foo','foo@example.com');
insert into members(name, email) values('Anotherfoo','foo@example.com');
```

So I know I need to remove the existing constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE members DROP CONSTRAINT members_email_key;
```

But how do I create a new constraint that does what I want? I have been looking at the `EXCLUDE`-clous but do not fully understand how to apply it. I have tried some variations of this without success:

```
ALTER TABLE members ADD CONSTRAINT email_for_valid_members EXCLUDE USING gist (email with =, ...
```

Documentation about `EXCLUDE`:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html

I'm using postgresql 9.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a partial unique index:

```
create unique index only_one_active_email
   on members(email)
where not archived;
```